# Flash Builder 4.6 sqlite database location

Tags: flash, sqlite, builder

When running the flash builder 4.6 emulator, where is the sqlite database stored? I can't seem to find it anywhere. Any help or comments are appreciated.

Comment: I finally figured this out. It is in the Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\APPNAME

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:

```
C:\Users\[ user name ]\AppData\Roaming\[ your app ]\Local Store
```